# Android service stopping when kept the application runnning for some time

Tags: android, android-service

I am creating an application that has to be run continuously till the user clicks a stop button. What the service do is that if gets the current latitude and longitude by using GPS and uploads to the server. But when I keep the application running for a long time the service stops uploading data. Can anyone please tell me how to keep the service running continuously until the user presses the stop button? Please give me a solution for this issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are interested in making your service STICKY.

When Android runs out of memory it will stop your service so that it can continue working. If you set the sticky flag to your service, then the service will be recreated once enough resources are available.

You make a service sticky like that:

```
public class YourService extends Service {

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // We want this service to continue running until it is explicitly
        // stopped, so return sticky.
        return START_STICKY;
    }
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have worked on same requirement, here is the solution i am using,

Class : `AlarmManager` & `TimerTask`

Logic,

1. Create a TimerTask Class that uploads your GPS Co-Ordinates on server on regular interval.
2. Create an AlarmManager Class that stops and starts GPS and TimerTask on specific interval ( in my case 30 minutes ).

this works like charm.